# Converting WKT to WKB in Java using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, java, well-known-text, well-known-binary

How can I convert a WKT string to a WKB byte[] in Java using PostGIS functions?
I need to save that WKT string in a PostGIS database (geometry column.

Answer (score 1):

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html#OpenGISWKBWKT

says that you can convert it like that in both ways:

```
bytea WKB = ST_AsBinary(geometry);
text WKT = ST_AsText(geometry);
geometry = ST_GeomFromWKB(bytea WKB, SRID);
geometry = ST_GeometryFromText(text WKT, SRID);
```

Comment: You want the last of these, just use ST_GeometryFromText and let the database handle the text to binary conversion for you implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save WKT in geometry column, you can do this in pure SQL using ST_GeomFromText function. Look at [the docs](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) to see the possible options.