# Finding format/type of the vector geometry

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry-data-type, bulgaria

Does anybody know what format is the following element?

```
01000000804AE9B78F8F0D416258AE25F8E45141
```

It looks like WKB or PostGIS geometry/geography but I didn't manage to convert it.

It has to be point in the centre of the city of Sofia, Bulgaria. The coordinate system should be EPSG:32635. There are some other attributes of the SRS:

```
FalseX=-5120900; FalseY=-9998100; XYUnits=450445547.391054; FalseZ-1000; ZUnits=2147483.645; FalseM=-100000; MUnits=10000; IsHighPrecision=1; XYTolerance=0.001; ZTolerance=0.001; MTolerance=0.001
```

But I don't know if I should create user defined CRS with these elements.
The coordinates of this point given in another table are (198; 4733). If I use them with the standard EPSG:32635 the point is located far more South.

Comment: Where and how did you receive that string?

Comment: It is part of a database. It is not created by me, I just want to receive the geometries. Now I see only attribute tables.

Comment: I would like to get information like "It comes from PostGIS by doing SELECT geometry from my_table limit 1".

Comment: I don't know how the database is created. It was provided to me in ACCESS format. I'm not even sure if it is PostGIS database, because I tried to import this point in a simple postgis table with one geometry (also with geography) but I received "Wrong WKB format" error.

Comment: I would ask from the one who sent the Access database for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting for this, but losing time. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be an odd number of hex-couplets, so I tried adding an extra "01" (the WKB code for point geometry, I think) at the start and converting with R's wkb package:

```
> readWKB(list(hex2raw("0101000000804AE9B78F8F0D416258AE25F8E45141")))
SpatialPoints:
          x       y
[1,] 242162 4690913
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

Saving that in an object with EPSG:32635 and then converting to 4326 (lat-long) gives me a point which is indeed in Sofia:

```
> pts = readWKB(list(hex2raw("0101000000804AE9B78F8F0D416258AE25F8E45141")))
> proj4string(pts)=CRS("+init=epsg:32635")
> spTransform(pts, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
SpatialPoints:
            x        y
[1,] 23.87071 42.32777
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:4326
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

So somehow an "01" has been chopped off the start of the hexadecimal WKB representation.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of Spacedman, you can use the QuickWKT plugin to get the point into QGIS.

Enter `0101000000804AE9B78F8F0D416258AE25F8E45141` in the input box and select `Point (WKB)` as Data type. The result is near the town of Momin Prohod.

[Converting WKT to WKB in Java using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79442/converting-wkt-to-wkb) gives a few more hints on WKB to WKT conversion.

BTW the coordinates `(198; 4733)` are Sofia City in UTM 35N, but in kilometers instead of meters.

Comment: Yes, my fault. The hex value is the village of Momin (Prohod) and the coordinates are for Sofia. I had coppied different lines. However, thank you very much for the help.